# Clickonce multi browser support

Tags: wpf, deployment

I am using clickonce for my deployment for my wpf applications, but the problem is its not suitable for chrome,firefox or any other browser

Is there any alternative available like click once ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a. Solution though click is not suitable for chrome edge and Firefox as .application extension is not suitable rather you can use the same setup.exe which is part of the click once deployment and that exe will execute the .application file automatically when you click it